# How to get rid extra space between rows in report?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am new to *JasperReports* and I couldn't find a post here yet regarding extra space between rows. I have tried all possible combinations in the configuration but i still get that extra space.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Here is my .jrxml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 5.6.1.final using JasperReports Library version 5.6.1  -->
<!-- 2014-09-24T10:15:09 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4_Table_Based2" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="fc97a963-c0b6-4c19-a348-7e2773e092a3">
    <property name="template.engine" value="tabular_template"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="New Data Adapter (8)"/>
    <style name="Table">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#EFEFEF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="tableDataset" uuid="0a703f7e-a572-40e6-b9a7-1408781b7b0c">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="New Data Adapter (8)"/>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <group name="Group1"/>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="userId" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="userType" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <columnHeader>
        <band>
            <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="40" splitType="Immediate">
            <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" mode="Opaque" x="20" y="20" width="100" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="bf862bec-5e45-4ac1-9d66-5a2e62e7007d"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{userId}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="10" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: i have solved it by updating the height attributes of the detail band and the report element as the same value, e.g., 16 for both... however, i had to do it in the design mode as it is throwing an error if i do it in the source code. btw, i have used the jaspersoft plugin in eclipse.

Comment: Please make your solution comment an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jaspersoft : Extra space at the end of table in detail band](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33366424/jaspersoft-extra-space-at-the-end-of-table-in-detail-band) & [iReport (JasperReports) extra row issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8354126/876298) & [How to remove extra space between rows in JasperReports?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3657517/876298)