# Jaspersoft : Extra space at the end of table in detail band

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using jaspersoft studio 5.6. I created a table in detail band to display data from database (it expands to many pages). And when in the new page, at some point, it generates extra space at the end. You can see in the image I uploaded here, when in record 23rd, it generates extra space below, but from 25th it not. Can someone help me on this problem? It make me confuse.

[jrxml file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B67iLaVdX01MU3FtazZ3cnRhUlk/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: where is code? and if possible add expected output. image here is not enough.

Comment: need jrxml to try to understand why.

Comment: I uploaded my file, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is what happens according to me (can't test but you can)

1. Your detail band is height=65
2. Your table is at y=15 height=50

If you do not have enough rows your table will never arrive to height=50, so since detail band is 65 you will have the space below the table, hence table starts at 15, runs for 2 rows give height=40, there will be 10 space until detail band ends.

**Solution:**

Make the `height` of your table as 1 row in it 20!, and reduce the detail band to fit height=35

The tag you need to change on the table is:

```
<componentElement>
   <reportElement x="0" y="15" width="511" height="20" uuid="b3d3ccdb-1d82-4bb3-81f6-e0690e70519b">
```

- tag on detail band

  ```
  <detail>
   <band height="35" splitType="Stretch">
  ```